# UIMA RUTA: Italics

Tags: uima, ruta

Does anyone know how can I search for all words in a text that are italicized? And to extend that, search for specific words that are (or are not) italicized?

For example, given "I am *certain* that I am not mistaken", I'd like to extract `certain`, or extract all `am`'s that are not italicized?

Comment: Whether your input file is html or xml?

Comment: Send me a sample input

Comment: Hi @Sugunalakshmi.G The sample input is html.
The RUTA documentation [link] (https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.pdf) mentions bold and underline, but not italics.

Comment: Italic will come under uima.ruta.type.html.I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the formatting information is present in the CAS, e.g., by applying the HtmlAnnotator (in combination with HtmlConverter) provided by Ruta, the rules could look like (as indicated in a comment of the question):

```
I{-> MyType};
SW.ct=="am"{-PARTOF(I) -> MyType};
```

You maybe need to import the HtmlTypeSystem of Ruta.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*